# T-SQL for determining if a Stored Procedure exists in Sql 2012

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012

This code:

```
SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE type = 'P' AND name = 'proc_name'
```

finds the 'proc_name' stored procedure in a Sql 2000, but it doesn't for Sql Server 2012.  A variation on this, which looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.objects  WHERE   object_id = OBJECT_ID
(N'ap_tems_delete_temp_itinerary_item]') AND type IN ( N'P', N'PC')
```

Also doesn't work in Sql 2012.

What DOES Work?

**EDITED FOR CLARIFICATION**

The point of the question is that when one uses this template:

```
IF EXISTS (select * from sys.procedures where name = '$SchemaQualifiedObjectName$')
BEGIN
   DROP Procedure  $SchemaQualifiedObjectName$
END
```

in Visual Studio to generate a stored procedure creation script, it generates the name of the procedure in square brackets, qualified with [dbo].  And when this script for the stored procedure creation is run, this does not work:

```
IF EXISTS (select * from sys.procedures where name = '[dbo].[stored_proc_name]')
BEGIN
   DROP Procedure [dbo].[stored_proc_name]
END
```

The is because the name of the stored procedure does not contain dbo or square brackets.  I have to edit them out, but I don't want to have to.  The format of using OBJECT_ID() actually works, but not when you have a square bracket mismatch, which is what my problem actually was, and is what @Ebis pointed out.

I do know that `select * from sys.procedures where name = 'stored_proc_name'` does work -- but not if square brackets are present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-- use both brackets or let them away...

```
SELECT Object_ID FROM sys.objects  
WHERE   object_id = OBJECT_ID (N'[ap_tems_delete_temp_itinerary_item]') 
SELECT Object_ID FROM sys.objects  
WHERE   object_id = OBJECT_ID (N'ap_tems_delete_temp_itinerary_item')
```

Comment: This answer actually caught my syntax error -- bracket mismatch!

Answer (score 0):

Since  SQL 2005, Microsoft started to use more structured naming for system object like sys.***

the easiest way is:

```
select * from sys.procedures where name = 'proc_name'
```

Comment: This actually doesn't work when $SchemaQualifiedObjectName$ generates [dbo].[stored_proc_name].  Whereas *object_id = OBJECT_ID (N'[ap_tems_delete_temp_itinerary_item]')* does work.  It's the square brackets that are the killer for this line.

Comment: I don't get why you say it does not work. I just ran "select * from sys.procedures where name = 'rptusp_TDRTrend'" and it returned the right result.

Comment: Did you see the part about the square brackets?  The name of the stored procedure in the script I'm generating in Visual Studio comes across as '[dbo].[sproc_name]'.  If I remove the square brackets and the dbo it does work, but that's a manual step.  I needed something that would work even while leaving the brackets and the dbo.

Comment: You have a missing bracket, but you don not need bracket at all. when you generate script, SQL Server adds bracket to the generated script, but it doesn't mean you have to use bracket, unless you object name is not standard (it has space or dot or any other non-permitted character)

Comment: Actually you don't need to use object id. the query I posted as answer, returns the expected result.

Comment: You're not getting it, @FLICKER.  See my clarification in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this,

```
SELECT *
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
WHERE  ROUTINE_NAME = 'PROCEDURE_NAME'
       AND ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE'
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way, without directly querying SQL Server system tables (which is always preferred when you can avoid it) is using Information_Schema:

```
Select * 
From Information_Schema.Routines 
Where Routine_Type = 'Procedure' And Routine_Name = 'proc_name"
```